# Is the notion of similarity a value judgment similar to morality?

Tags: objects

Can two things/objects/events be **intrinsically** more similar to each other than another pair?

By this, I mean can two objects be similar to each other in a mind independent way? After thinking about this issue, a similarity relation seems to be similar to how we perceive morality and make value judgments.

“Killing a baby is wrong” seems more intuitive to more people than “hitting someone back harder than they hit you is fine.” And yet, what makes the former intrinsically more “correct” than the latter? I fail to see how this is possible without smuggling in certain assumptions.

Similarly, a cup is similar to a bottle more than a bottle is to a blanket. But is this also smuggling in certain assumptions such as valuing the property of shape and size more than say the position of the room? For example, if the bottle and blanket were both to the right of you and the cup was to the left, with respect to the position of the room, the similarity relation would change.

Lastly, how do we know if our intuitive feel for what’s similar applies to just us based off of our own personal biases vs. some level of intuition that we all share. For example, I’m pretty sure almost all people would find one cup similar to another cup compared to other subjects. This perhaps come from a shared bias. But intuitions that come from a bias personal to us but not shared by others can also feel just as strong. How do we differentiate them?

Comment: Those philosophers, always smuggling things! Maybe people who judge things more similarly are more similar?

Comment: Nelson Goodman was even harsher in his famous critique of similarity where he called the concept "*invidious, insidious, a pretender, an imposter, a quack*", which is useless for philosophical purposes, and only usable in practice when heavily constrained by context. This became a consensus in analytic philosophy for a while, but, with some qualifications, similarity was rehabilitated in more recent times, see [Similarity After Goodman](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3339023/).

Comment: See a recent *similar* [post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/95459/is-the-subjective-nature-of-similarity-a-weak-point-of-analogical-inductive-reas) about the subjective and context-dependent nature of similarity and also the famous family resemblance concept in analytic philosophy of language...

Comment: In the case of position, you're judging the _locations_ to be similar to each other, not the objects themselves. I don't think an object's _placement_ is a property of that object.

Comment: Similarity is a judgement because you need to choose which qualities to measure. This requires a mind to choose, so therefore it cannot be mindless or objective.